# Rails Google OAuth2 + Devise - Could not authorize you from Google oauth2 because "Timeout"

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timeout, google-api, omniauth

So I've been working on the Google API for a long while now going through this tutorial I found on the internet: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview and it almost worked for me. I did all the steps specified and I successfully managed to redirect to Google to request access for my application from the sign in page. However, when I click "Allow access", the server redirects me to the ordinary sign up page and I get a flash saying:

> Could not authorize you from Google oauth2 because "Timeout"

Gem used:

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

This is in my devise.rb model:

```
require "omniauth-google-oauth2" 
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "myKey", "mySecret", { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
```

And this is the route:

```
devise_for :gamers, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "gamers/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Comment: Hey did you manage to find an answer to this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue :(